# Darkening background-color of React styled-component on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, hover, styled-components, background-color

I want to make my custom div's background color change on hover. It is a styled component and the color is passed in by props. However, with the code below, the hover effect is not working.

```
const ColorBlock = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.fillColor || "blue"};
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 5px solid black;

  &:hover {
    background-color: ${props => props.fillColor * 0.5};
  }
`;
```

The hover effect works if I just pass a color for the hover background-color:

```
 &:hover {
    background-color: blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the `CSS` property `background-color` dosn't accept the given `Syntax` values in this piece of your code :

```
background-color: ${props => props.fillColor * 0.5};
```

example of some of `background-color` property usage :

```
/* Keyword values */
background-color: red;

/* Hexadecimal value */
background-color: #bbff00;    /* Fully opaque */
background-color: #bf0;       /* Fully opaque shorthand */
background-color: #11ffee00;  /* Fully transparent */

/* RGB value */
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128);        /* Fully opaque */
background-color: rgba(117, 190, 218, 0.5);  /* 50% transparent */

/* HSL value */
background-color: hsl(50, 33%, 25%);         /* Fully opaque */
background-color: hsla(50, 33%, 25%, 0.75);  /* 75% opaque, i.e. 25% transparent */
```

one solution would be :

```
&:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.hoverFillColor};
  }
```

full [sandbox-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-sanne-cz21q1?file=/src/App.js)
more about [background-color-CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color#syntax)

Comment: That should work. I am going to try to find a way that doesn't require inputing two different colors since I want the hover color just to be a darkened "fillColor"